# How to successfully pass data from Controller to View?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I have modelled and am now testing a Database for a PHP (CodeIgniter 4) web application. I made a function in my (products) Model that retrieves data from the DB and called that function in the controller.

```
    getBasicInfo(int $id): array
    {
        $db = $this->connectToDB();

        $query = $db->query('SELECT productName, productDescription, productType FROM konnektrix_db.products WHERE productID = $id LIMIT 1');
        $row = $query->getRow();
        return
            [   $row->productName,
                $row->productDescription,
                $row->productType
            ];
    }
}
```

```
class Home extends BaseController
{
    public function index()
    {
        $ProductModel = new Products();
        $data = $ProductModel->getBasicInfo(1);
        //$data['name'] = 'Yuna';

        return view('testing_view',$data);
    }
}
```

What i want is to be able to access that data ($data) from my view (testing_view) but when i do, it doesn't recognise the variable. (refer to image for error)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Data testing view</title>
</head>
<body>

<h2>General product overview page</h2>

<h1><? $data; ?></h1>

</body>
```

Any idea on what i might be doing wrong?

I have looked at multiple sources on how to pass data from Controller to View in CI4, this is what they did unless i am missing something?

[View error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLX4n.png)

Comment: Please do not use screenshots of your code or error messages and do not link to external sources. Screenshots are hard to read on mobile devices, they cannot be searched and none of us can copy, paste and run an image, links can get obsolete. Code should be included as text in the question itself. For more on this see 
[**Why may I not upload images of code**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) 
on SO when asking a question?

Comment: @Vickel I included the code that is seen in the screenshot but i get your point. The error is just the variable $data being undefined.

Also, the query does produce results but its besides the point since i tried it with a local variable in the controller $data['name'] = 'Yuna';

and it still says the Variable is undefined in the View, also using the correct notation you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

According to [documentation](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/outgoing/views.html#adding-dynamic-data-to-the-view) you should call the variable using the [escape function](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/outgoing/view_renderer.html?highlight=esc#escaping-data).

Please try:

Adding string identifiers to the array from getBasicInfo function.

```
getBasicInfo(int $id): array
        {
            $db = $this->connectToDB();
    
            $query = $db->query('SELECT productName, productDescription, productType FROM konnektrix_db.products WHERE productID = $id LIMIT 1');
            $row = $query->getRow();
            return
                [   "name" => $row->productName,
                    "description" => $row->productDescription,
                    "type" => $row->productType
                ];
        }
```

And then something like this in your view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Data testing view</title>
</head>
<body>

<h2>General product overview page</h2>

<h1><? esc($name); ?></h1>
<h1><? esc($description); ?></h1>
<h1><? esc($type); ?></h1>

</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, i will try that in a bit but using a local variable 

$data['name'] = 'Yuna';

in the controller still wont work, also when escaping the variable like you said.

Comment: using esc() doesn't make any difference for this example, but anyway it is good practice.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass an array to a view the array gets 'exploded' out.
So `$data['name']` becomes `$name`.

So just search for variables with the array keys as the names.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the clarification. I did just try this though and it still doesn't recognize $name in the view, same error.

Comment: I just noticed it's returning an array function.  You need to name your array keys not use the default of 0 , 1 , 2